# Boostrap modal dialog blacks out when parent div has transform: translate

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, transform

It seems to be a Bootstrap bug. When I put a modal dialog inside a `<div>` that has **`transform: translate(60px)`**, the whole modal dialog is *blacked out* by its own `modal-backdrop`.
See here for the bug example: http://jsbin.com/benonopixa/1/edit?html,output

Any idea how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that `div.modal` and `div.modal-backdrop` are not siblings in your example—they're…cousins. Why are you wrapping your modal in `container`?

Comment: Yea if I move div.modal outside of container or move backdrop inside using js, the problem will be solved. But I have to place modal in container, because I have no way to generate the modal content outside of the main container.

Answer (score 0):

**you have style error at this line check it out**

```
 <div class="container" style="-webkit-transform: translate(60px);transform: translate(60px);width:800px;height:800px">
          <h1>Bootstrap bug report</h1>
```

use below code to solve it

```
<div class="container" style="-webkit-transform: translate(60px);width:800px;height:800px">
      <h1>Bootstrap bug report</h1>
```

Comment: No. transform: translate(60px) isn't a style error. And no, it doesn't resolve it.